# Find time of the shortest distance between two accelerating points in a plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> Given two points $A$ and $B$ in a plane, with initial positions $P$ and velocities $V$, and constant accelerations $a$, find solutions for what value of $t$ (in seconds) they will be the closest?

I would imagine if I started with a set of values for the 6 variables it would be easier as I could simplify a lot, but in my case I need to find $t$ for any $P_A$, $V_A$, $a_A$, $P_B$, $V_B$, $a_B$.

I have solved this problem for when there is no acceleration, and my approach there was to create a function for their positions, and then a distance function $d(t)$ using the Pythagorean theorem, and then minimizing $d(t)$ by solving for $d'(t) = 0$.

I tried this same approach for this case with acceleration, and solving it in Wolfram Cloud gave me a few solutions for $t$, however, each solution was more than a 1000 symbols long, with many complex parts, so not very practical to use for my case (a simulation). Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to find common normals to the two trajecteries.

Comment: @Mann Wouldn't that only give me the positions of the trajectories that are the closest? And not the time that the two points were the closest? (as the points could be far away from each other at a position where the trajectories are close)

Comment: You can simplify your calculations for the minimum quite a bit. First, change coordiates so that point A is stationary at zero and B has parameters $P_B-P_A$, $v_B-v_A$ and $a_B-a_A$. Next it is sufficient to minimize $d(t)^2$, so you ignore the pesky square root. Unfortunately this still comes out to a third degree polynomial in $t$. This has $3$ complex solutions, which one is the one you need might depend on the parameters you picked.

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to work out the solution in the relative frame of reference. Let the point $A$ be the origin. The initial position and velocity of $B$ in this relative reference frame are,

$$\vec{P}_{ab}=\vec{P}_b - \vec{P}_a,\>\>\>\>\>\vec{V}_{ab}=\vec{V}_b - \vec{V}_a$$

Because of the constant acceleration for both, there is no net acceleration for $B$ in the reference frame of the choice, which greatly simplifies the problem.

As a result, the distance vector as a function of time between $A$ and $B$ is then simply,

$$\vec{D}_{ab}(t) =\vec{P}_{ab} + \vec{V}_{ab}t$$

Square both sides,

$$D_{ab}^2(t)=P_{ab}^2+2\vec{P}_{ab}\cdot\vec{V}_{ab}t+V_{ab}^2t^2$$

To minimize the their distance, take the derivative with respect to time $t$ and set it to zero, which leads to the time for them to be the closest,

$$t_m = -\frac{\vec{P}_{ab}\cdot\vec{V}_{ab}}{V_{ab}^2}
= -\frac{(\vec{P}_b - \vec{P}_a)\cdot(\vec{V}_b - \vec{V}_a)}{|\vec{V}_b - \vec{V}_a|^2}$$

Note that the solution, i.e. positive $t_m$, exist if $\vec{P}_{ab}\cdot\vec{V}_{ab}={P}_{ab}{V}_{ab}\cos\theta<0$, i.e. their initial relative position and velocity vectors form an obtuse angle $\theta$. Their initial distance is already the closest if $\cos\theta>0$, i.e. moving away from each other.

Edit in response to OP's comments below:

In the case where the relative acceleration is not zero, (dropping subscribe $ab$ for briefty)

$$\vec{D}(t) =\vec{P} + \vec{V}t+\frac12 \vec{a}t^2$$

Then, the corresponding equation for solving $t_m$ is,

$$a^2t^3+3\vec{V}\cdot\vec{a}\>t^2 +2(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{P}+V^2)t +2\vec{P}\cdot\vec{V}=0$$

The cubic equation has one real solution for $t_m$. For example, you could use the Cardano's formula in the link below. It is rather involved, though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation

It may be of interest that in the special case of $\vec{V}\perp\vec{a}$, the cubic above reduces to $t^3+pt+q=0$, with

$$p=\frac{2(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{P}+V^2)}{a^2},\>\>\>\>\>q=\frac{2\vec{P}\cdot\vec{V}}{a^2}$$

Then, the solution for the time is,

$$t_m= \left(-\frac q2+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}\right)^{1/3}+\left(-\frac q2-\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}\right)^{1/3}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This looks pretty good, but can I just ignore the acceleration completely? Note that the two points can have different accelerations

Comment: @SofusØvretveit - I interpreted the question as both having the same 'constant' acceleration. Otherwise, the problem is intractable.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear about that, but yeah the accelerations are different for a and b

Comment: @SofusØvretveit - If the two accelerations are different, their net is not zero. The resulting solution for time is rather complex, involving solving a cubic equation. I added additional formulas in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea you have seems to be working. Using a Taylor series, write
$$
A(t) = P_A+V_A\cdot t+\frac{1}{2}a_A\cdot t^2, \\
B(t) = P_B+V_B\cdot t+\frac{1}{2}a_B\cdot t^2.
$$
The goal is to minimize $d(t)$, i.e. find $t$ such that $d'(t)=0$, where
$$
d(t):=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(A_i(t)-B_i(t))^2}.
$$
For a plane $n=2$, thus $A=(A_1,A_2)$. Note that this would work in any dimension. You can now write down $d'(t)$ and equate it to zero, which gives you a real, 3rd-order polynomial, which has three complex solutions. Good luck!

Comment: Calculus is a good idea, but it's best to try minimising $d^2$ instead to avoid the surd.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am wondering, wouldn't this just be the same approach as I initially tried? Which leaves me with the solutions I already have for t which are more than a 1000 symbols long

Comment: Possibly, and possibly you already have to correct answer to your problem. It looked like you were partly looking for a second opinion to assure yourself you were using the correct method. However, with my answer I also meant to imply that you write down the 3rd-O. polyn. $d/dt[d(t)^2]=0$ by hand or using software and substitute the coefficients in the generic solution to a 3rd-O. polyn. Maybe that way you can understand your solution better and write down a more concise form than Wolfram Cloud can (perhaps due to lack of assumptions).